$state object could not be cloned
After I switched to Svelte 5 syntax I am getting this error when I pass a reactive variable to a function
let details = $state({
  user: '',
  pass: ''
})

// ...
await login(details) // <- error

but works if I spread the state variable:
await login({ ...details })

Why is spreading needed in Svelte 5 but not 4, and why is it not mentioned in the migration guide?

What does the login function look like? I'm not able to reproduce this

it just calls ipcRenderer.invoke("login", data). It seems related to this ipcRenderer issue, but this doesn't explain why I get this error before it reaches invoke, I get it in the auth wrapper function which simply calls window.request(). window.request is a function exposed in the preload script that calls ipcRenderer.invoke

I think from what i'm seeing you shouldn't pass variables created with $state to anything outside svelte. your svelte 5 code results in let details = $.proxy({ user: '', pass: '' });.
whereas your svelte 4 code resulted in let details = { user: '', pass: '' };. Destructuring retrieves the raw object out of the Proxy. Either it should be mentioned in the migration docs, or it just isn't good practice, i'm not too familiar with electron

await login({...details}) is not destructuring. It's taking a shallow copy of details.

State that wraps objects or arrays creates a Proxy, this allows Svelte to fire change signals for each property access individually (previously the entire object was invalidated). Proxies cannot be cloned and the spread operation removes the proxy.
If you hand off your state to a third-party API, the recommended approach is to get a plain object via $state.snapshot.

I think this was a bad arch decision by svelte. It's very common you need to pass things outside of svelte, like to utility functions. So now we have to wrap everything inside snapshot...
